# Why am I redirected to a certain port on a website while using Tor?

Tags: security

While browsing websites using Tor (on tails), it sometimes happens that instead of `www.website.org`, `www.website.org:8123` is displayed in the URL bar. In this case the website is not working.

When I use a normal browser instead, however, this redirection does not happen and the website works properly. Is there any explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Are you just using native Tails, or have you also set up a proxy as well?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this behavior on my own servers,
it happens when for example apache hosts many sites on separate ports.
When the site does not not properly (as you mention) then it shows the port in the url bar - even if you did not enter that port during the initial connection.
The usual setups is to have each site listen on port 80, but sometimes different setups are used.

This would also happen if you used the browser bundle.

When you go to 'example.url' , then the apache server hosts that site on port 81 instead of 80 (basically forwarding it from port 80 to port 81 internally) then this can happen.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the result of a misconfiguration of some other software running on a number of Tor exit relays.

It's occurring when the destination web server redirects a user to another page on the website. The software on the exit is misinterpreting the redirect request and rewriting the request to port 8123.

I'm not sure what software is causing this behaviour. The offending exit operators have been informed and have hopefully fix the problem by now.

Comment: polipo uses 8123 by default